# HashSet.SetEquals on two identical collections returns false

Tags: c#, .net, hashset

I have two [HashSet<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.setequals?view=netframework-4.8) collections containing the same items (that is, different instances of the objects but with the same values).  From my understanding of the [SetEquals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.setequals?view=netframework-4.8) method the following code should return `true` because the collection item property values are equal, but it returns `false`:

```
var source = new HashSet<AllocatedComponent>()
        {new AllocatedComponent() {
            Weighting = 100,
            ComponentId = 1, 
            Title = "Foo"}};
    
var destination = new HashSet<AllocatedComponent>()
        {new AllocatedComponent() {
            Weighting = 100,
            ComponentId = 1, 
            Title = "Foo"}};
    
Console.WriteLine(source.SetEquals(destination)); // False
```

Can anyone please explain what I'm doing wrong here?  My goal is to check that the two collections contain the same number of items, and with the same property values.

I don't quite understand the Remarks section of the Microsoft documentation so may be overlooking something quite obvious.

[Net Fiddle here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jCcl0j)

Comment: Is `AllocatedComponent` an `IEquatable<AllocatedComponent>`? `SetEquals` has to defer to the equality comparison of elements to compare things; if there is none, you'll get the standard (reference) equality, where different instances never compare equal. Consider making `AllocatedComponent` a `record` so you get this for free.

Comment: Note that if you're doing this in the context of a unit test, many frameworks offer structural equality comparison without requiring you to make your objects directly comparable, e.g. Fluent Assertions' `Should().BeEquivalentTo()`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I was under the impression that the SetEquals method deals with the reference equality checks?  Is that not the case?  What do you mean by `a record` please?

Comment: `SetEquals` only takes care of the reference equality bit of the `HashSet` *itself*, not of the *elements* in the `HashSet`. By a record I mean [a record](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/record), available from C# 9 onwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As from the first comment to let the framework to compare the object using their data you have to override the 2 methods `bool Equals(object o)` and `int GetHashCode()`. The code below gives the desired result (please note that you have to use all the data members for both the implementations)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class AllocatedComponent
 
{
    public double Weighting { get; set; }
    public int ComponentId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    
    public override bool Equals(object o)
    {
        if(!(o is AllocatedComponent))
           return false;
        AllocatedComponent ac = (AllocatedComponent)o;
        return ac.Title == this.Title && ac.ComponentId == this.ComponentId && ac.Weighting == this.Weighting;
    }   
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return this.Title.GetHashCode();
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var source = new HashSet<AllocatedComponent>()
            {new AllocatedComponent() {
                Weighting = 100,
                ComponentId = 1, 
                Title = "Foo"}};
        
        var destination = new HashSet<AllocatedComponent>()
            {new AllocatedComponent() {
                Weighting = 100,
                ComponentId = 1, 
                Title = "Foo"}};
        
        Console.WriteLine(source.SetEquals(destination)); // False
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  So I can also add in comparison checks for the `Weighting` and `ComponentId` property values into the `Equal` method, to check them all at once?

Comment: Yes I edited the answer to give a full `Equals` method taking in count all the data memebers